# Сложность выполнения программы android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, мне попросили написать программу под android(сам в этой области мало разбирался), поэтому прошу совета сложно ли будет такое будет реализовать: программа через равные промежутки времени посылает на определённый номер смс и получает, если ответ "всё хорошо", ничего не делает, а если "всё плохо", выводит сообщение. Я на java писал, но под android ещё опыта не было.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы, буду разбираться-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз уж никто не отвечает) На сколько я знаю реализацию отправки смс можно найти в примерах. Чтобы смс отправлялась автоматически через определенный промежуток времени(а следовательно выполнялась в фоне, если я правильно понял) нужно реализовать сервис. Сервис будет постоянно запущен в фоне, отправлять смс и контролировать ответы. Если ответ такой какой вам нужен, то делаете одно, иначе делаете другое(выдаете сообщение, звуковой сигнал и т.д.). Работу вместе с обучением(если можете создавать приложения немного сложнее HelloWorld-ов) я бы оценил дней в 5.

Answer (score 1):

[Сайт три!](http://startandroid.ru/index.php) сложности не должно возникнуть

Answer (score 0):

Все просто. [Сайт раз](https://www.google.ru/), [Сайт два](http://developer.android.com/) и желание - все, что нужно, даже больше. Но вот  рассылками смс заниматься - не тру, я так думаю.

Comment: Прям интересно, за что минус.

Comment: @RomanoO, вот и у Вас появился повод попросить @ХэшКод сделать **обязательным комментирование минусов**

Comment: Пожалуй, не обязательным, а по требованию, а если минус не аргументирован, то возвращать его в 10х размере.
avp, как вы считате мой ответ противоречит правилам ХэшКод или, может, он просто неадекватен?

Comment: Насчет "если минус не аргументирован, то..." IMHO неадекватен. Я имею в виду скорее **обязательный выбор из предопределенных вариантов**, а если среди них нет устраивающего, то ввод текста комментария.

Иначе процесс обучения (IMHO выставление оценок часть обучения) страдает.